# SKLearn TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_frame'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have two lines of code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine

X, y = load_wine(as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)
```

And I'm getting the following message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-a85f1453ccf2> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
      2 
----> 3 X, y = load_wine(as_frame=True, return_X_y=True)

TypeError: load_wine() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_frame'
```

If I take off the argument as_frame the code works fine, but it isn't what I need.

How do I fix it? Thank you

Comment: can you confirm the version of sklearn you are using.  ` as_frame` parameter was introduced in 0.23 .

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_wine.html

Comment: I'm using google collab, I dont know how to check that in a collab.

Comment: import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)

Comment: Oh, I see. The version is 0.22.2.post1.
Do you know how to import the last version or 0.23? Thank you man

Comment: in your collab , try  !pip install scikit-learn==0.23.1

Comment: Thank you, good man. Everything works fine. If you want answer the question saying the problem was solved in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_frame` parameter was introduced in scikit-learn 0.23 version.

To install the scikit-learn 0.23 version, use the following command :

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.23
```